# Laravel tests de navegador

Tags: laravel, windows, test, navegador-web, dusk

Estoy intentando crear tests de navegador, tal como se describe en la documentación de Laravel, en https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk. El problema es que tengo que desarrollarlos en una máquina Windows 8. Cuando intento ejecutarlos con `php artisan dusk`, el test se ejecuta, pero no funciona la parte que debería abrir el navegador para visualizar el comportamiento. En la consola el test me informa de ello, así: `Warning: TTY mode is not supported on Windows platform`. Esto siginifica, según entiendo y he cotejado en varias fuentes, que la emulación del navegador no puede correr en Windows.

Lo que me gustaría saber si esta limitación procede del propio Laravel, o del paquete dusk y, en este último caso, si existe algún paquete alternativo que me permita hacer estos tests de browser en Windows en un proyecto Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error no proviene del Laravel sino del paquete Dusk.

Mira esta solución alternativa que ofrecen [**aquí**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416870/errors-running-laravel-dusk) (Stack Overflow en inglés).

En resumidas cuentas, indica que utilices **ChromeDriver** y que configures el Laravel (fichero DuskTestCase) para que en vez de atacar Dusk, ataque ChromeDriver.